# JPEG2000 Transparency with JasPer Library

Tags: c, jpeg2000

I'm attempting to use [JasPer](http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/) JPEG2000 library to create transparent JPEG2000 images (actually I'm creating JPCs).

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to make JasPer create a transparency image. None of its supported formats support transparency (with the exception of the JPEG2000 formats, which are what I'm trying to create):

```
The following formats are supported:
    mif      My Image Format (MIF)
    pnm      Portable Graymap/Pixmap (PNM)
    bmp      Microsoft Bitmap (BMP)
    ras      Sun Rasterfile (RAS)
    jp2      JPEG-2000 JP2 File Format Syntax (ISO/IEC 15444-1)
    jpc      JPEG-2000 Code Stream Syntax (ISO/IEC 15444-1)
    jpg      JPEG (ISO/IEC 10918-1)
    pgx      JPEG-2000 VM Format (PGX)
```

In the JasPer documentation it uses the word "transparency" once in this context:

> A RGBA (i.e., RGB with transparency) image would have four components,
>   one associated with each of the red, green, blue, and alpha planes.
>   The various components need not be sampled at the same resolution. In
>   other words, different components may have different sampling periods.
>   For example, when color images are represented in a
>   luminance-chrominance color space, it is not uncommon for the
>   luminance information to be more finely sampled than the chrominance
>   information

That implies that transparency is supported, since it is discussing how transparency works in the encoding. And yet... how to use it?

Any ideas?

Also any other open-source alternative that supports the creation of transparent JPCs would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I understand this is not an answer and goes against rules, but I have nowhere else to ask. I want to build the JasPer library and link it to LibRaw dynamically in visual studio. The sln gets generated from the dsw file and I can't understand how to build the dynamic version. The configuration type is set to .lib, and I can't find the preprocessor definition needed to build it dynamically. E.G. in linux I could use --enable-shared in the config. Can you help?